# Prevent or Catch Dialog on dismiss with (back button or clicking the barrier to quickly) or force to wait until ScaffoldMessenger.of finishes

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a dialog that dismisses too fast and throws an

```
 Unhandled Exception: This widget has been unmounted, so the State no
 longer has a context (and should be considered defunct).
```

Before `ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackbar(widget)` can send the context to the `SnackBar`

screen1.dart:

```
 launchVendorCard(vendorId)  async {
    
   vendorCardResult = await showDialog(context: context,
                builder: (builder) => VendorCard(vendorId));  }
```

vendorcard.dart:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context)  {
 return Dialog( 
           ...
          ElevatedButton(

          child: Text(buttonText,),

          onPressed:  () async {
                var snack =  await SnackBar(
                content: Text("$vendorTitle"),

                duration: Duration(seconds: 3),);

              await ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snack);
              Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop(true);
              // Navigator.pop(context, true); )
)
```

How do I prevent this? `await` doesnt work.
Gets triggered by quickly pressing close button, or tapping outside the barrier too quickly

Comment: Try to use Navigator.pop() only

Comment: `await SnackBar(` what? Does that even compile? Please post a [MCVE].

Comment: @nvoigt sorry bout that. I now added relevant chunks of code

Answer (score 2):

You can wait after the `SnackBar` is dimissed with the [SnackbarClosedReason](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SnackBarClosedReason.html) by using the `closed`. It returns a `Future` with the reason why the `SnackBack` got dismissed. After it has been dismissed, it will then execute the `Navigator.pop()`

```
var snack = SnackBar(content: Text("$vendorTitle"),duration: Duration(seconds: 3));

final snackBar = ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snack);

// Waits until SnackBar got dismissed
await snackbar.closed;

Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop(true);
```

Comment: it seems that this gets disregarded when the dialog is dismissed quickly either by tapping outside, pressing the back button, or quickly pressing my close button. the snackbar's context gets lost and would not build

Answer (score 0):

- I used `WillPopScope` to catch the dismissal problem.
- Disable my close button when there's an operation in the background that needs to finish.
- Moved the `Snackbar()` to the main page and just pass the info I need from the `Dialog()` by creating a map that is passed to `Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop(map_object);`